# Issues loading twitter data in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, nsxmlparser

In my app i am getting status from a twitter handle using this:http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/ABCD.xml
But sometime it just doesn't show anything in my tableview. I am using NSXMLParser.
Here's the code :

```
Class A : 
 xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/ABCD.xml"];

XMLParser.m


    -(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
    {
        //spinnerControl = [[SpinnerController alloc]init];
        //[spinnerControl getAlertViewWithSpinner];
        tweets          = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData *data    = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
        NSString * result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Complete:%@",result);
        parser.delegate = self;
        [parser parse];
        return self;
    }



    -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"status"])
        {
            currentTweet = [Tweet alloc];
        }
    }

    -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
    {

            currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    }


    -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"text"])
        {
            currentTweet.content = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if (alreadyHaveDate != 1)
        {
            if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"created_at"])
            {
            currentTweet.dateCreated = currentNodeContent;
                alreadyHaveDate = 1;
            }
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"profile_image_url"]) {

            currentTweet.artistImage = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
            currentTweet.artistName = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"screen_name"]) {
            currentTweet.screenName = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"status"])
        {
            [tweets addObject:currentTweet];
            alreadyHaveDate = 0;
        }
        //[spinnerControl  removeAlertView];
    }

Tweet.h :
@interface Tweet : NSObject
{
    NSString     *content;
    NSString     *dateCreated;
    NSString     *artistImage;
    NSString     *artistName;
    NSString     *screenName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString   *content;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString   *dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString   *artistImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString   *artistName; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString     *screenName;
@end

Tweet.m

@implementation Tweet


@synthesize content, dateCreated,artistImage,artistName,screenName;


@end
```

Specially in the case of when the device is on 3G.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code for the parse function, but how do you know you are actually getting some data back from the API?

You say that this is especially in the case of when the device is on 3G, so you probably want to validate that you can reach the API and that you don't have null data before you try and parse it.